# Problems with using a dll in a JNI-created dll

Tags: java, c++, dll, visual-studio-2005, java-native-interface

I am working on a Java project in which I have to use a third party dll (let's say abc.dll). So I created a native header file using JNI.

Then I created a dll project on vs2005 (typical win32 app.) and added that header file created by JNI. I selected clr old syntax support for the project and added the abc.dll as a reference to my project.

Up to now, everything is ok. Here is the problem. I implemented the methods defined in the header file using some methods from the abc.dll. abc.dll has a class called "abc" and that's what I do:

```
abc *abcObj = new abc(); abcObj->callSomeMethod();
```

I take a build from the solution, everything is ok. But when I run my Java program, I get an error from the JVM telling that native code broke down?!?! I debugged it and the problem is in new(). It simply cannot instantiate the abcObj.

Then I tried with a c++ app using that abc.dll. It worked.

I think there must be problem with JNI or that managed/unmanaged thing. I am not really experienced at c/c++ so I don't understand so much (at least I don't have time to understand for now). Only thing I try to do is create a wrapper dll using the third party dll and use the wrapper dll in my java app.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

-haydar

**edit:** I have all the dlls that are needed by my third party dll.

Comment: Any chance the DLL's that are required for all of this to work are NOT in the load-path ? Ie. if the DLL's needed by your JNI cannot be loaded from the working directory, PATH environment variable, or windows and system32 folders, you'll get this error.

Comment: I fear you *will* need to spend some time for a basic understanding of JNI :-) I would start with a very simple approach: leave aside your third party dll, and implement a method which for instance returns the sum of two integers. Once this works, you can extend it with all necessary methods and also add your third party dll.

Comment: @Andreas absolutely the case. Start small and conquer the world when your old enough.

Comment: @Andreas I have already done this before I started. By the way the problem is not loading. The dll is loaded and until I create an abc object everything is fine.

Comment: Then we need some more context. Simply creating an object on the C++ heap usually does not crash the JVM. What is the exact error message which is printed ("Native code broke down")? Which JDK version are you using? How do you initialize the JNI? Again, I would still pursue the step-by-step approach: start with your running sample JNI application, and add step by step additional code (ideally using a version control system and check in the code after each step).

Comment: @Andreas Ok. I started with a small sample just adding two integers. I got it running. I could use the add function from Java. Then in vs2005 project I activated clr support and added abc.dll as a reference. Then in the add function I called `abc ^abcObj = gcnew abc();` I added nothing more to the code. When I call the add function from Java now, it says "a fatal error has been detected by JRE. JRE version 6.0_33 . The crash has occured outside Java virtual machine, in native code.

Comment: Could the CLR support be an issue? I am not very familiar with CLR - why do you need this in your case? Which flag is passed to the compiler (is it /clr:pure)? What happens if you do not activate clr support? Could it be that the abc() constructor throws a C++ exception (add a try { } catch (...) {} block around it and do some debug output in the catch block)?

Comment: /clr flag is passed to the compiler. Well, I add clr support so that I can add the third party dll as a reference. When I add a try-catch block and add a GetLastError() insinde catch, it returns error code 1004 sth like "invalid flags".

Comment: @Andreas When i don't add clr support to the project, I can't add references. In that case, i load the dll using LoadLibrary function. I can use the functions in the dll with the help of GetProcAddress but I don't know how to use the structs declared in the dll. I mean there are some structs declared in the dll and some functions require parameters in those types.

Comment: Try using another class except abc, some class that you wrote by yourself (just like the integer sum example). If that works then there is something fishy in the abc's constructor.

Comment: @JakubZaverka but i can call abc's constructor from a c++ aplication. the thing is that when i call it via Jni from java it gives error.

Comment: I am trying to determine if the problem is in Java in the first place. Have you tried to 'new' anything else than abc?

Comment: @JakubZaverka There is not another class in the dll but there are structs. I tried to new them and did not get any errors. Then I saw that when I put mouse over "abc" it is written `__gc class abc`. can it be because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The problem was that I was creating the project as a win32 application and choosing dll then. I created a clr application and everything went well. I followed the instructions from [here](http://codefry.blogspot.com/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html).